# The logic of the vscode custom link jump cannot open the link

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image]

I found two related APIs, go to define and custom editor, but so far testing go to define doesn't seem to work for markdown links (of known type), maybe go to define doesn't support blocking links and supports code level jumping?

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors

The code is as follows

```ts
  vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider(
    {
      scheme: 'file',
      language: 'markdown',
      pattern: 'edit-*.md',
    },
    new JoplinMarkdownProvider(),
  )
  
export class JoplinMarkdownProvider implements DefinitionProvider {
  provideDefinition(
    document: TextDocument,
    position: Position,
    token: CancellationToken,
  ): ProviderResult<Definition | DefinitionLink[]> {
    console.log('provideDefinition: ', document, position, token)
    return undefined
  }
}
```

---

Update, `registerDefinitionProvider` can intercept clicks, but the returned Uri cannot be opened

For example, https://github.com/ will cause an error when opening

```js
Unable to open'': Unable to resolve resource https://github.com/.
```

In addition, the query part of the custom schema link will be escaped

The shape is like `vscode://rxliuli.joplin-vscode-plugin/open?id=03c8b00ed350410baf41c33daddf3005` => `vscode://rxliuli.joplin-vscode-plugin/open?id%3D03c8b00ed350410baf41c33daddf3005`

It will also report an error

```js
Unable to open'open': Unable to resolve text model content for resource vscode://rxliuli.joplin-vscode-plugin/open?id%3D03c8b00ed350410baf41c33daddf3005.
```

The specific error code is at: https://github.com/rxliuli/joplin-vscode-plugin/blob/12854b05da7901a8655f69c90b65f56b67acc73f/src/extension.ts#L147

[image]

> ref link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8466